How to solve errors when creating chrome extensions using TensorFlow.js?
I am making a chrome extension to apply a filter to the face in google meet, but I get the following error. Does this have anything to do with the filter breaking up?
The error is as follows
error
Your application contains ops that are small enough to be executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot be found. Consider importing the CPU backend (@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu) for better performance.
context
https://meet.google.com/~
Stack trace
tf-backend-webgl.js:6587 (MathBackendWebGL.shouldExecuteOnCPU)
    var _this = this;
            if (sizeThreshold === void 0) { sizeThreshold = CPU_HANDOFF_SIZE_THRESHOLD; }
            var cpuBackend = this.getCPUBackend();
            if (!this.warnedAboutCPUBackend && cpuBackend == null &&
                !tf.env().getBool('IS_TEST')) {
                console.warn('Your application contains ops that are small enough to be ' +
                    'executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot ' +
                    'be found. Consider importing the CPU backend ' +    ```


" console.warn('Your application contains ops that are small enough to be" is drawn.

I do not know how to solve it.

